# Good mode to edit CSV files including adding and removing columns?

Tags: major-mode, spreadsheet, csv

Looking for a mode to edit CSV files. I tried [`csv-mode`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/csv-mode.html) which is great for viewing CSVs via the minor mode `csv-align-mode`.

However I cannot find an easy way to add or delete columns in this mode. Is this possible in `csv-mode` or is there another mode for CSV files allowing this?

Comment: There are [several spreadsheet packages](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpreadSheet) available; [table-mode](http://table.sourceforge.net/) might be of interest; and you can use the [general rectangle commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) to insert columns. In general I just reach for another tool when I need to do serious work with "csv" files

Comment: @nega Thx for chiming in. In the spreadsheet packages I couldn’t find one that operates on CSV file buffers. Creative idea to use the rectangle commands - will try whether it works with a Csv file in csv-align-mode. :-)

Comment: If you want to filter rows, none of the packages can help.I was also looking for one a few years ago. Have not found any yet

Comment: @nega The rectangle commands work perfectly in csv-align-mode! Would you like to write up an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv-insert-column` to add a column, and with the whole buffer selected `csv-kill-fields` will delete columns.